# redis - add multiple values to a list and fetch multiple values

Tags: php, redis

I don't know if `list` is the right data type?

I need to add a lot of items to a list and then I have to fetch all items.. After an item is fetched it must be removed

```
$list = 'the:list';
$redis
    ->multi()
    ->lRange($list, 0, -1)
    ->lTrim($list, -1, 0)
    ->exec();
```

The above code fetch the items but doesn't delete them after they are fetched? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You code should work. A better way is to delete the list: `MULTI && LRANGE && DEL && EXEC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading them back out sequentially you can use [LPOP](https://redis.io/commands/lpop) or [RPOP](https://redis.io/commands/rpop) which will remove it from the list and return it.

If you need to read them out randomly, then maybe use a SET rather than LIST data type, then you can use [SPOP](https://redis.io/commands/spop)

**UPDATE**
Based on a few comments you've made along with your original question, it sounds like you want to read out the entire list and then delete it, but you are concerned about items being inserted between the read & delete operations?

If that is the case, then use a redis [transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions). Use [LRange](https://redis.io/commands/lrange) followed by a [DEL](https://redis.io/commands/del) on the key. As you can see from the docs, the transaction ensures nothing affects the list between the two operations, so any new additions to it, will simply end up re-creating the list.

> All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed
>   sequentially. It can never happen that a request issued by another
>   client is served in the middle of the execution of a Redis
>   transaction. This guarantees that the commands are executed as a
>   single isolated operation.

Or in other words, replace your trim, with a delete and you're good to go.

Comment: `pop` is too slow when there are many items.. so thats not an option

Comment: `LPOP` and `RPOP` are O(1) operations. How many items make it appear slow for you?

Comment: I have benchmarked with a mysql table and at some point it becomes faster to use mysql to fetch the entries compared to redis.. Can't remember the amount right now.. I just realised that `pop` was not gonna work.. I need to fetch all entries in one go

Comment: OK, think I understand what you want. Your question comes across as sequential read-out but your own code is a bulk read out hence the confusion. So you just want to get all the items and then delete them in bulk, but without risking deleting anything coming in from another client... So you just need to replace your trim with a delete in your original code and away you go.

Comment: ok.. So this would work `$entries = $redis->multi()->lRange($buffer_list, 0, -1)->del($buffer_list)->exec()[0] ?? [];` ? :)

Comment: @clarkk Yep. LRange to fetch the entire list, Del to delete it afterwards, wrapped up in a transaction so if anything tries to add to the list, it will wait until you've fetched and removed the current contents of it 

Answer (score 1):

Once you fetch the data.Then you could expire the key.

For Example:
https://redis.io/commands/expire

Comment: What if new items are pushed to the list in the mean time?